# Removing duplicates from an array (without sets or sorting)

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayDuplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers are you going to enter? ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[num]; // initialize array with user inputted length
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // enter numbers into array
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        int[] unique = new int[arr.length];    //initialize new array that will hold unique values
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            boolean b = true;    //boolean that checks if an element is a duplicate
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {    //check all elements above int i
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    b = false;    // set b to false if there is an existing duplicate
                }
            }
            if (b) {
                unique[i] = arr[i];    // if no duplicates exist, then it is unique.
            }
        }   
        for (int i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(unique[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code (aside from being horribly slow for large arrays, but that's not the point) is that since the undeclared elements for the `unique` array will be set to `0`, the duplicate elements from the first array are being set to `0` in `unique[]` (if that makes any sense). I understand why this happens, but cannot find an efficient way to fix this. I tried setting the duplicate elements to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in the unique array and then printing only the elements of `unique[]` which are not equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, but that seems like a weak solution to the problem. How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:** If I run the code:

> How many numbers are you going to enter? 4
>   1
>   2
>   2
>   0

Output:

```
1
0
2
0
```

Since the second element of the array is a duplicate, I do not set `unique[1]` to any value, making it default to 0. How do I avoid printing that 0, since it is not part of the original array?

**EDIT 2:** Yes, this is homework, but the reason I don't want to use sets, sorting, etc. is primarily that I am not familiar with them. Also, as I am not asking anyone to write the entire program for me, I think it's fine to ask for a little help.

Comment: Im afraid it doesn't make any sense to me, perhaps you could reword what you are trying to say in your question?

Comment: Have you considered not adding duplicates to the array in the first place?

Comment: You could count the unique elements in `arr` before creating the `unique` array

Comment: Without using a List or Set the solution gets extremely messy. If you have to not use a List or Set, i'd just suggest setting duplicate values to Integer.MIN_VALUE, like you said, or creating a parallel of boolean values

Comment: Java arrays are not dynamically sized, so you can't *remove* an element without more code. Also, the `Map` or `List` are not a `Set` or sorting.

Comment: *"I think it's fine to ask for a little help."* - My help is in the form of advice.  Learn how to use your IDE's debugger.  Seriously.

Comment: @StephenC There are no bugs/errors with the program. I was simply asking how I could improve my code and/or make it more efficient.

Comment: @Kootling My solution below allows you to enter any integer value even negative. It is your own code, but optimized and has added a parallel array for comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to use the tools that you used to solve the problem, cuz something in me is telling me this is homework...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayDuplicates 
{

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("How many numbers are you going to enter? ");
      int num = scan.nextInt();

      int[] arr = new int[num]; // initialize array with user inputted length

      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)// enter numbers into array
      {

         arr[i] = scan.nextInt();

      }

      double[] unique = new double[arr.length];    //initialize new array that will hold unique values

      ///////My edit

      for(int z = 0; z < unique.length; z++)
      {

         unique[z] = -0.5;

      }

      ///////

      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
      {

         boolean b = true;    //boolean that checks if an element is a duplicate

         for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++)    //check all elements above int i
         {

            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) 
            {

               b = false;    // set b to false if there is an existing duplicate

            }

         }

         if (b) 
         {

            unique[i] = arr[i];    // if no duplicates exist, then it is unique.

         }

      }   

      for (int i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) 
      {

         if(!(unique[i] == -0.5))
         {

            System.out.println((int)(unique[i]));

         }

      }

   }
}
```

So, you see where I commented out my edit? that's the new thing, a very easy way to check is to give the values a number that is **not** expected, in this case, a negative number. Now, that is an assumption on my part, change -1 to whatever value you know will **not** be entered into that `Scanner`. Same for the if statement.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me, as it is what I was thinking to do at first. However, I do not know what values will not be entered, so I decided to use a `double array` and use `0.5` as the value that will not be entered (the inputted values should be integers, so 0.5 should not be entered).

Answer (score 4):

Any value that you choose (zero, min-int, max-int) to represent a removed duplicate is a problem.  The user could always enter that number, and your program wouldn't behave correctly.  (The only way you could legitimately use (say) min-int or max-int would be if the requirements clearly said that that number was invalid input.)

The correct way to deal with duplicates is to keep a counter of the number of non-duplicates, and make sure that the duplicates (or slots that would contain them) are at the high end of the array; i.e. indexes >= the counter.  (That becomes an invariant that your algorithm needs to maintain ...)

The best solution is to eliminate the duplicates before you add them to the array.  Keep a count of the number of non-duplicates and iterate until that reaches your `num` ... rather than the length of the array.

But if you do want to add all values to the array and *then* eliminate the duplicates, when you find a duplicate you need to swap elements so that you can maintain the invariant.  The logic is a little bit fiddly ... but quite doable.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that your original solution was using two arrays.  I assumed that you were using one array, and doing an in-place update to eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: That is true, and I admit, that is a flaw in my answer, but the OP admitted that this is homework and only wants an answer that uses tools the OP knows how to use and can deal with a reasonable set of inputs. Your point is still valid, it's just that this is homework that the answers are dumbed down

Comment: *"The idea to to have a quality answer for anyone to use."* - The quality answer to the functional requirements (as stated) is to not use an array at all.  (Using an array is not a **functional** requirements.  It is an implementation constraint ... that doesn't make much sense for anyone trying to write quality code for Java SE, EE, Android.)

Comment: So what I understand is that I should check each inputted integer with the previous inputs and only add it to the original array if it is unique. Also have a counter that counts how many inputs have been added to the array (i.e. inputs that are unique). Then create a new array of length `counter` which contains the first `counter` elements of the original array. Is this what you are saying? In this case I would not need to ensure that the duplicates are near the end of the array, correct?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper - No comment.  My answer was actually for the OP ... in the hope that he was going to attempt to do the homework himself.  But feel free to submit your own answer to the teacher, and ask him to mark it for you :-)

Comment: @Kootling - You've understood what I was saying.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you. However why do you state that I would need to `make sure that the duplicates...are at the high end of the array`?

Comment: Maybe I misspoke.  It depends on whether you eliminate the duplicates before or after.  In the former case, you are right.  The duplicates shouldn't be in the array at all, and the slots greater than the 'count' position can be left in their initial state.  (Just don't print them ...)  Anyway, you should think it all through for yourself rather than taking my (or anyone else's) word for it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use a [**Map**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
public interface Map<K,V>
```

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate
>   keys; each key can map to at most one value.

I don't know why you would not want to use a set unless you are doing homework...

---

**If you really can't use a set**. Go ahead and create an `ArrayList`. Store the elements of the `array` inside, but everytime you want to store you check if the element is already part of the `ArrayList`.

```
 int [] list = {5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5};

 ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    if(!list2.contains(list[i]))
        list2.add(list[i]);
```

You can, if you want, turn your `ArrayList` back into an array.

```
Object[] list3 = list2.toArray();
```

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper I know how to do it with an `ArrayList`, but wow a `Map` is just so clean.

Comment: It's a tool that was built for this sort of thing

Comment: Yes, this is homework, but the reason I don't want to use sets, sorting, etc. is primarily that I am not familiar with them. Also, as I am not asking anyone to write the entire program for me, I think it's fine to ask for a little help.

Comment: @Kootling do it with an ArrayList like I did above.

Comment: @Kootling do you know how to use ArrayList, or are you familiar with it?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper Unfortunately no, I have not gone over `ArrayList`s yet.

Comment: @Kootling Perhaps my answer might help? Scroll down a little

Comment: @Kootling just read what an `ArrayList` is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html In short it is a more powerful array.

Comment: `Perhaps my answer might help? Scroll down a little` @DreadHeadedDeveloper you totally scavenged my post, but I don't hate you as long as OP learns :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the maximum value entered by user (while the user is entering the values in the first loop) and then make the default value for unique equals to max + 1.

Or you can try another approach for solving the problem, something like this:

```
  int num = scan.nextInt();
  int[] arr = new int[num];
  int[] uniq = new int[num+1000000];
  int j = 0;

  // enter numbers into array
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
     int input = scan.nextInt(); 
     if(uniq[input] != 1){
         uniq[input] = 1;  
         arr[j] = input;
         j++;
      }
   } 

   for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
   }
```

Note that this solution is under the assumption that the user will not enter a number greater than `(num + 1,000,000)`.

Comment: Hmmmm, the OP is worried about inefficiency, I have to give a -1 for lack of efficiency, since it's something the OP specifically asked for...

Comment: But this takes only O(num + j).. So actually this's more efficient :)

Comment: That doesn't mean anything when you are creating a million unit long array... efficiency can cap off when the individual load of an action outweighs the efficiency of that action

Comment: There's a trade-off between performance and storage, performance wise, it's efficient, note that we're not going to iterate over them at all.

Comment: Regardless, creating that array will take time, time the OP is already pressed for. Perhaps I misspoke, the OP is concerned about time, and every unnecessary action is detrimental to the OP, if you look at my answer, a little type-casting quickly solved the issue of permitted responses without going overboards

Answer (score 1):

This solution allows you to enter any integer value even negative. It's your same code with some modifications and has added a parallel array for comparisons.  It has also removed some lines of code that are no longer needed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many numbers are you going to enter? ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[num]; // initialize array with user inputted length
    int[] arrflag = new int[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // enter numbers into array
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        arrflag[i] = 0;
    }

    int[] unique = new int[arr.length];    //initialize new array that will hold unique values
    int n=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {            
        if (arrflag[i] == 0) {
            unique[n++] = arr[i];
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {    //check all elements above int i
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {                        
                    arrflag[j]=-1;
                }
            }                
        }
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(unique[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a parallel character array with all the values as '.' Whenever you find a duplicate, set the value to a ',' in the character array. Then Print only the values of your array that have a corresponding '.' in the character array.

```
 }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(a[i]=='.')
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Example with String [].

```
public static List<String> arrListWithNoDups(String arr[]){

    Map<String, Integer>map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    List<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(map.get(arr[i]) == null){
            map.put(arr[i], 0);
        }
        else{
            map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i])+1);
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j<arr.length; j++){
        if(map.get(arr[j])==0){
            list.add(arr[j]);
        }
    }

    return list;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class RemoveDuplicateFromArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 5};
    System.out.println("Before removing duplicate" + Arrays.toString(myArray));

    RemoveDuplicateFromArray rd = new RemoveDuplicateFromArray();
    int[] newArray = rd.findDuplicate(myArray);
    System.out.println("Before removing duplicate" + Arrays.toString(newArray));
}

public int[] findDuplicate(int[] inputArray) {
    Arrays.sort(inputArray);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < inputArray.length && inputArray[i] == inputArray[i + 1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[inputArray.length - count];
    int c = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
        if (j + 1 < inputArray.length && inputArray[j] == inputArray[j + 1]) {

        } else {
            result[c] = inputArray[j];
            c++;
        }
    }
    inputArray = result;
    return inputArray;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried to improved this code, please comments/suggest if further improvement can  be done.

```
public static int[] removeDuplicate(int[] arr) {
    int[] noDuplicates = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        boolean b = true;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
                b = false;
            }
        }

        if (b) {
            noDuplicates[i] = arr[i];
            System.out.print(noDuplicates[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    return noDuplicates;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

```
void myFunction(int arr[])
{

    int size=arr.length;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
        {

            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                arr[j]=arr[size-1];
                size--;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int a=0;a<size;a++)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[a]+" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: While your code actually seems to accomplish what the title of the question asks, it doesn't relate to the code provided in the question. Also, your answers should always be accompanied by an explanation to make reading easier for people unfamiliar with the topic.